# 6 errores AL COMPILAR MI APLICACIÓN

Tags: android-studio, compilador

He tenido unos errores muy molestos a la hora de compilar mi aplicación, no he podido visualizar mi aplicación por causa de estos errores.

> 03:41 PM  Emulator: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
>
> 03:41 PM  Emulator: OpenGL backend 'angle' without OpenGL ES 1.x
>   library detected. Using GLESv2 only.
>
> 03:41 PM  Emulator: Failed to eglInitialize
>
> 03:41 PM  Emulator: Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
>
> 03:41 PM  Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES
>   emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
>
> 03:41 PM  Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819
>   (0xC0000005)

Comment: Por lo que alcanzo a ver, los errores no son de la aplicación, si no del emulador, intenta probar la aplicación en un dispositivo real o en un nuevo emulador

Comment: Definitivamente este problema es en el emulador, en ocasiones se tiene problemas con la tarjeta de gráficos y no puede funcionar correctamente.

Comment: Que recomendacion me harias?

Answer (score -1):

Este problema en realidad se produce en el emulador que estas usando, ve a el `AVD Manager` y edita el emulador que produce el problema.

Da clic en el botón <kbd>Show Advanced Settings</kbd>, en la sección "Emulated performance" selecciona que los gráficos sean emulados en Software:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: eso ya lo hice y no lo resuelve.

Comment: El error indicado se resuelve con esto, si no funciona al menos indica que otro error se muestra.